# How to get the number of features after one hot encoding in Pyspark ML pipeline?

Tags: pyspark, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I'm preparing to do some KMeans clustering with PySpark. When I am assembling my features, I'm doing some one hot encoding first and applying some specific weights with ElementwiseProduct last. I'm looking for a way to obtain the number of features (in my assembled feature vector) *right before* the elementwise product step, so that I can use it to create my scaling vector and pass it as the scalingVec parameter in the ElementwiseProduct transformer.

Here is some code that shows what I'm trying to do, where `n` in the last stage `transformer` is what I am missing.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, StandardScaler, VectorAssembler,  ElementwiseProduct
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

indexer = StringIndexer(
  inputCols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
  outputCols=['col1_idx', 'col2_idx', 'col3_idx']
)

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(
  inputCols=indexer.getOutputCols(),
  outputCols=[x + "_feature" for x in indexer.getInputCols()]
)

assembler = VectorAssembler(
  inputCols=onehotencoder.getOutputCols(),
  outputCol='features_raw'
)

scaler = StandardScaler(
  inputCol=assembler.getOutputCol(),
  outputCol="features_scaled"
)

# add specific weights to the first two features, 1 for everything else
transformer = ElementwiseProduct(
  scalingVec=Vectors.dense([4.0, 2.0] + [1.0]*(n-2)), 
  inputCol=scaler.getOutputCol(),
  outputCol="features"
)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, onehotencoder, assembler, scaler, transformer])
```

I realise I can obtain the necessary number if I take the `transformer` out of the pipeline, transform the data, obtain `n`, and then do the last elementwise product. I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to break up my pipeline, but also where the pipeline won't fail if the number of features changes.